# Why did BASH print "bash: cd: write error: Success"?

Tags: bash

I noticed this several times today. If I type `cd ../Directory` to change to another directory, it prints "bash: cd: write error: Success". I can't determine what other previous commands might be related to this.

- `typeset -f` prints nothing.
- `alias` prints nothing.
- `type -a cd` prints "cd is a shell builtin".
- `echo $CDPATH` prints an empty line.
- `$BASH_VERSION` prints "bash: 4.2.37(1)-release: command not found".
- I only noticed this 2-3 times. The initial directory and target directory were identical in both situations. I changed directories in this manner many other times, but did not encounter the error always.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please add the output of `type -a cd` as Glenn requested.

Comment: Please add the output of the `type` command to your question. Also, does this happen in all directories or only if you are in a specific one(s)? And what is the output of `echo $CDPATH`?

Comment: What exact bash version (in `$BASH_VERSION`) are you running?

Comment: I have `bash 4.2.37(1)`.

Answer (score 6):

#### Maybe a bug?

This sounds like a potential bug. I found a similar report showing the same message. The bug [bash: pwd builtin exits with write error: Success](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=243872).

*excerpt*

> This message will be displayed if ferror(stdout) returns non-zero.  For
>   some reason (probably the fflush() call immediately preceding the check),
>   stdio is causing ferror() to return true without setting errno.
>
> Does this happen twice in a row?  The pwd builtin calls clearerr() after
>   printing the error message, so even if the stdout error flag `sticks',
>   that should clear it.

#### Can't update history?

The error makes me think that it was successful in changing directories, but wasn't able to write the command `cd ../Directory` to your `$HOME/.bash_history`. I'd confirm that this file is intact and is writable. Also confirm that your `$HOME` directory is writable and not full.

```
$ df -h $HOME
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home  402G  157G  225G  42% /home
```

Comment: The `/home` partition has much space available. I cannot find anything strange in ".bash_history", it is set to read and write only for the owner. Whenever I quit a terminal, the data from that terminal still goes there. Is is possible this came up because I was running multiple terminal windows at the same time?

Comment: @Village - perhaps, but each time a command is run in a shell it should get a lock on the history file and release when it's done, every other process doing the same would just wait.

Comment: bash does not write to `~/.bash_history` immediately after running the command, but after the session closed, right?

Comment: @Pemapmodder - correct, it was unclear to me if the OP had done something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate/67306#67306.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and I'm quite sure that it is not true (because I was `su root` at that time, and I instantly `tail /root/.bash_history` and saw nothing relevant, then `exit` to back to my normal user, then `sudo tail /root/.bash_history`, and the line (both lines, since I repeated the `cd`) was indeed written.

Answer (score 3):

Your cd command is either an alias or most likely a bash function.

```
typeset -f  # displays functions
alias       # display aliases
```

If not found with the above commands `which cd` will locate the path of the `cd` command.

Look for the `cd` alias or function definition in the normal start scripts `.bash_profile`,  `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Comment: `typeset -f`, `alias`, and `which cd` all return nothing, and the other files only contain `PATH=~/.context/tex/texmf-linux/bin/:$PATH`.

Comment: use `type -a cd`

Comment: `type -a cd` prints "cd is a shell builtin".